# "Pyaudio" pip install fails for every package even after upgrading pip

Tags: python, pyaudio

I downloaded the package  `PyAudio-0.2.11-cp39-cp39-win_amd64` and copied it in the script file in python 3.9 directory, but when i tried to install the pack pip throws me errors

```
ERROR: No matching distribution found for PyAudio-0.2.11-cp39-cp39-win_amd64
```

I tried to upgrade pip as a solution that i found it here in Stack :

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

then:
pip install PyAudio-0.2.11-cp39-cp39-win_amd64

but pip keeps failing with an this Error :

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyAudio-0.2.11-cp39-cp39-win_amd64
`ERROR: No matching distribution found for PyAudio-0.2.11-cp39-cp39-win_amd64`
```

I also tried

```
pip install pipwin 
pipwin install pyaudio
```

is there any other  solutions please ?

Answer (score 0):

Maximum officially supported version of python for pyaudio is `3.6`; quoting from the [Installation](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/#downloads) page:

> Microsoft Windows
>
> Install using pip:
>
> ```
> python -m pip install pyaudio
> ```
>
> Notes:
>
> If pip is not already bundled with your installation of Python, get it
> here. pip will fetch and install PyAudio wheels (prepackaged
> binaries). Currently, there are wheels compatible with the official
> distributions of Python 2.7, 3.4, 3.5, and 3.6. For those versions,
> both 32-bit and 64-bit wheels are available.

You could read about installing different versions of the python on your machine and use it with 3.6 version of python without any errors

Comment: thank you that helped , if python 3.9 is not supported so  why there is a package Pyaudio 39 for 64-bit wheels ?

Comment: It's unofficial python packages that could be installed offline. You can find another unofficial packages here for example https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio. But officially supported stopped on 3.6 version of python